# Display certain page only after login in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

How to display menus list only when the user is logged in to the site.But as of now the user is able to see the menu by giving direct URL.If the user is logged in then only he can be able to see the menu list and all.Can anyone check this.
HTML Code:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="accountantApp">
<div class="container jumbotron"  ng-init= "getAddressInfo()" ng-controller="AddressInfoController" id="homejumbotron">
    <div class="col-sm-12 primary">
        <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all personal">PERSONALINFO</a></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="login.php" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">LOGOUT</a></div>
   </div>
```

Js:

```
var app = angular.module('accountantApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('AddressInfoController', function($scope,$http,$timeout) {
$scope.submitAddressInfo = function(isValid, user) {
    if (isValid) {
        console.log("address info::"+$scope.user);
        $http({
              method    : 'POST',
              url       : '../model/addaddressinfo.php',              
              headers   : {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            },
              data      : {'addressinfo': $scope.user, 'action': 'Save'}

            }).success(function(data, status, headers) {

                console.log("Response data:"+ data.error);
                if (data.success != undefined && data.success != '')
                {
                    console.log("inside success");
                     window.location.href = "income_source.php";
                    $scope.getTemplate("ADDRESSINFO");
                    $scope.user = '';

                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.error = data.error;
                }         

            }).error(function(data, status, headers) {
                 window.location.href = "error.html";
                console.log("Error data::::"+ data);

                alert("Error occured while creating address info:"+status);
                        });         
        }
         else{
        $scope.submitted = true;
        alert("Fill the form.");
        return;
    }

};
```

Comment: assuming that you have a logincontroller add authentication flag in your scope (e.g. `isAuthenticated` ) and set this flag to true once user is logged in. In your views add `ng-hide` directive to your links and use the value of isAuthenticated flag

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi i am not getting what you are saying

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi can you update me one example

Comment: look how I set the flag when i login successfully 
https://jsfiddle.net/9as2ac3d/

Comment: Actually i just started to learn angular iam aware of this can you please do in my code

Comment: the html part in my example is my menu. I added checking when to show the menu links using the isAuth property

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit unclear and the controller code you posted seems to be unrelated.

But assuming that all you want to do is show/hide something depending on whether or not the user is logged in, then you could do it like EuphoriaGrogi said, create a variable that is set to true if the user is logged in and false if not. Something like this:

```
    $http.post('login_url').then(function(response){
       if(login_successful){
            $rootScope.isAuthenticated = true;
       }
       else{
            //handle error
       }
    });
```

when you logout set it to false. In the html use an ng-if on whatever you want to hide:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 primary" ng-if="isAuthenticated">
        <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all personal">PERSONALINFO</a></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="login.php" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">LOGOUT</a></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: $http.post('login_url').then(function(response){   Here you gave as login_url but from where we have to give login_url function

Comment: So you haven't implemented the login/logout functionality in your app yet?

Comment: Ya i implemented login,signup functionality in php and it is working in php now i am working with angularjs

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with php but from what i know the standard login/signup in php won't work with angular, you have to convert it to an api.  After that call the login function like you did with the submitAddressInfo function you posted above in your example. You can look at satellizer for implementing the login/logout in your angular app: https://github.com/sahat/satellizer